# show error message after validating - jQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a function which compares two fields.

```
$.validator.addMethod("validatormethod", function (value, element) {
    return $('#Field1').val() > $('#Field2').val()
}, "Test");
```

The form is dynamic and hence the form is validated using `each`:

```
$('.validateclass').each(function () {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            validatormethod: true,
            messages: {validatormethod: "Test" }
        })
    });

$('.validateclass2').each(function () {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            required: true,
            messages: {required: "This field is required" }
        })
    });

$('#myForm').valid();
```

Now my problem is the message `Test` appears as soon as the page loads. It should appear only after the field is compared. I know it is due the the line `$('#formSaveComponent').valid();`. But I want the required message to appear when the page loads. Is there some way I can get this done using jQuery Validate plugin.

[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h4bf10vt/1/)

Comment: Show the HTML for your form.  Also explain more about why you're triggering `.valid()` when the page loads and what your title is supposed to mean.  Showing error message after validation is the default behavior.

Comment: I am triggering as there are many fields and for some fields, I want the validation to trigger as soon as the page loads. Not after clicking the submit button.

Comment: Setting .Valid() on the form load will run for every field on the form at the time it's loaded, which is why "Test" is showing up. If you only want some things to validate, you should specify the fields you want to validate, not the entire form.

Comment: You still need to click the edit link to clarify the question  for the reader and add some relevant HTML.

Comment: check the small fiddle I have created, what I am trying to do is, Trigger the error message `Test` after the submit/tab event.

Comment: You have never explained the point of this custom method.  Your jsFiddle is comparing first name to last name... how/why is one "text" field supposed to be evaluated as "greater than" the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"Now my problem is the message Test appears as soon as the page loads. It should appear only after the field is compared."*

You've written your custom method as if the fields are `required`... that is why you're getting the error message immediately and while the fields are still empty.

As long as these fields are not `required`, you would need to add `this.optional( element ) ||` to your custom method as follows...

```
$.validator.addMethod("validatormethod", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional( element ) || $('#Field1').val() > $('#Field2').val()
}, "Test");
```

Now the custom method will not fire unless something is entered into the relevant fields.

---

**EDIT 1**

Although I have no idea why, in your jsFiddle, you are comparing `txtLastName` to `txtFirstName` with a `>` comparison operator... exactly how could one name be "greater than" the other?

---

**EDIT 2**

[Your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4bf10vt/1/) is broken because...

1. You are targeting fields by `id`, however your fields only contain a `name` and no `id`.
   Change `$('#fieldname')` into `$('[name="fieldname"]')` to target them by `name`.
2. You are comparing two strings with a comparision operator, which will always fail because strings are not numbers.  You need [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert the string into an integer in order to compare them...

   ```
   parseInt($('[name="fieldname"]').val())
   ```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/h4bf10vt/3/**

Comment: this works, but the message 'Test' appears even if it is a proper(valid) field

Comment: @user2281858, that makes no sense as error messages are never shown when fields are valid; and why I've twice asked you to show the relevant HTML code in your question. I'll look at your jsFiddle, but as per this site's rules, jsFiddle are not substitutes for showing the code within the question itself.

Comment: @user2281858, my code in your jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/h4bf10vt/2/  ~ Explain exactly how & where this is failing.

Comment: i don't have the relevant HTML with me currently, but the behavior is same as the fiddle. I am comparing 2 textboxes, if one is greater than the other, the error message should appear.

Comment: @user2281858, again, how could one name be "greater than" the other?  The `>` comparison operator is for comparing two numbers... what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: i know one name cannot be greater than the other. the fiddle was just to demonstrate, please excuse the names. basically one field greater than the other

Comment: @user2281858, I solved your original question.  If the core function of your custom method is also broken, then you should have clearly explained the goal of your custom method in the OP.  However, assuming you're comparing two numbers... see my edited answer.

Comment: this is terrific, very precise.